# How to create the following Pie Chart

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a presentation with the fundamental of using Mathematica in Greek.

Normally I use Mathematica to present solutions to ODE problems.

Now I would like to create a pie chart with 10 identical segments in size 2.

I know that the code which creates a pie chart with 10 pieces is

```
PieChart[Range[10]]
```

My expectations of the result of the following code are as the following image shows.

```
PieChart[{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}]
```

[image]

My problem is the identical segments I don't know **how to define them in a shorter way.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like `PieChart[Table[2,10]]` ?

Comment: @rhermans yes that is very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @Syed Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I deleted my comment as the page updated and I found that the variation was already included in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
PieChart[Table[2,10]]
```

or [`ConstantArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html)

```
PieChart@ConstantArray[2, 10]
```

[image]